# Immediate response to the event in database should send signal to a Windows Service

Tags: c#, sql-server

The scenerio is:

I have an Sql server 2008. When an event occur in DB the database should inform
the windows service which should do some action.

I don't want to wait in the interval for the new tasks/db events to do something.
I need an immediate action.

What is the best approach to do this?

1. I thought about making a CLR assembly and linking it to the DB.
   The assembly then should connect to the windows service using e.g. tcp/ip
   Then the service is awaken and do the job
2. Or create a local inproc com assembly and load it from db

Thanks in advance for all the tips.

Comment: What kind of `events` do you want to capture? Also note the SQL CLR has more restrictions than standard CLR.

Comment: Are you looking to create a [CLR Trigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131093.aspx)?

Comment: @Lloyd A new row inserted/updated, etc. the method execution could be triggered in a table trigger.

Comment: @mbeckish I am looking for best approach in such scenerio

Comment: @John - Read the link I provided and let us know if that would work for you.

Comment: what happens if you send the signal and then the transaction rolls back?

Comment: @RemusRusanu nothing. Windows service would be triggered, check the database, and realize nothing had been really changed, so would quit and wait again

Comment: Did you consider what if the service would be triggered, check the database, and ... block because the triggering changes have not committed? And what if they don't commit for another hour?

Answer (score 2):

I'd create a windows service that includes a `SqlDependency`.

It functions a bit like a `FileSystemWatcher`, but for a sql database.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/a52dhwx7(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: Well it works unbelievable amazing.. Is it a reliable solution?

Comment: It has worked reliably for me, although it's a bit annoying to have it notify you that some data has changed and then have to go and query the table to find out **which** data has changed...